# Creating a for loop for sql data entry

Tags: sqlite, loops, for-loop

Currently I have this setup:

```
String string1 = ....
String string2 = ....
String string3 = ....
String string4 = ....
```

etc.

And then

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (" + string1 + ");");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (" + string2 + ");");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (" + string3 + ");");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (" + string4 + ");");
```

etc.

Is there a way to to create a for loop that runs through 1 to x implementing all? For example I tried:

```
for (int number = 0; number <= 4; number++) { 
    String s = "string" + number; 
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (" + s + ");");
```

However this didn't work. I then tried setting up:

```
String x[] = {string1, string2, string3, string4}`
```

then

```
for (int number = 0; number <= 4; number++) { 
     String s = "string" + number; 
     db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (" + x[number] + ");");
```

but that didn't work either.

Sorry if this is a newb question. I have looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What programming language? Java?

Comment: In theory, your loop over `x[]` should work. What error do you get?

Comment: Are you interested to get answer anymore. If yes, you should answer the comments

Comment: @j.w.r Java. Programming for android. Sorry, I really should've mentioned that :/ I've fixed it! I just had to create a string array of string1, string2 etc. rather than string + number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference this is how I implemented it

```
String[] sqlString = {string1, string2, string3...etc.}

db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            for (int n = 1; n < sqlString.length; n++) {

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES ("
                        + sqlString[n] + ");");

            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
```